# Opening a new hat notification doesn't work the first time

Tags: bug, notifications, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Sometimes, when opening a hat notification from the Winter Bash inbox, the hat does not show, and in the browser console I see an error like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: winterBashCurrentHats9495 is not defined
    <anonymous> https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/api/current-hats?callback=winterBashCurrentHats9495&userids=9495&host=french.stackexchange.com&_=1639945246320:1
```

I see it on multiple sites; the number after `winterBashCurrentHats` is my user ID on that site. If I click the notification a second time, the error is usually gone.

[image]